# Display using std::cout not work as expected

Tags: c++, cout

So I'm trying to make a school schedule that'd have text on the right side with text of a string I declared as `laikas[7]`. Note that it's in my native language (Lithuanian). My code is:

```
cout << " 1) Vokieciu\n" << laikas[0] << "2) Biologija\n" << laikas[1] << "3) Vokieciu\n" << laikas[2] << "4) Daile\n 5)" << laikas[3] << "Lietuviu\n" << laikas[4] << "6) Fizinis\n" << laikas[5] << "7) Anglu\n" << laikas[6];
```

The string:

```
string laikas[7] {"08:00", "08:55", "09:50", "11:05", "12:00", "12:55", "13:50"};
```

Yet the output is:

```
08:002) Biologija
08:553) Vokieciu
09:504) Daile
 5)11:05Lietuviu
12:006) Fizinis
12:557) Anglu
13:50
```

Any way to get the time on the right side? So for example it'd be 2) Biologija 08:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your new line should come after the laikas part, and adding a couple of tabs will make it look prettier aswell :)

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string laikas[7] {"08:00", "08:55", "09:50", "11:05", "12:00", "12:55", "13:50"};

    cout << "\n1) Vokieciu\t" << laikas[0] << "\n2) Biologija\t" << laikas[1] << "\n3) Vokieciu\t" << 
    laikas[2] << "\n4) Daile\t" << laikas[3] << "\n5)Lietuviu\t" << laikas[4] << "\n6) Fizinis\t" << 
    laikas[5] << "\n7) Anglu\t" << laikas[6] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```